# Why is useState inferring a type of SetStateAction<never[]> when I've explicitly stated the state variable should be of type <number>?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, state

I'm learning how to use TS and React together. I have a state variable declared with 'useState`:

```
const [lat, setLat] = useState<number>(0);
const [long, setLong] = useState<number>(0);
```

(note: I also tried `<Number>` as I've seen that syntax before and am not really sure which one is correct.)

However, when I try to set those values in a `useEffect` hook, I throw a `TS2345` typing error:

```
useEffect(() => {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position: Position) => {
    setLat(position.coords.latitude);
    setLong(position.coords.longitude);
  });
}, [lat, long]);
```

`Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.`

As far as I can tell, I've explicitly stated it should be of type `number`. And, [according to Microsoft's documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.coordinates.html), `latitude` and `longitude` are indeed of type `number`.

I've also added these `interface` objects for declaring types:

```
interface Position {
  coords: Coordinates;
}

interface Coordinates {
  accuracy: number;
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
}
```

Comment: `useState<number>(0);` you shouldn't need to specify the type of this because it can infer it will be a number from the initial value; `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position: Position)` you shouldn't need to provide explicit typings for the position argument either?; it all seems fine to me so I just copy pasted it out into my set up for a random project and I had no type errors and I did the same here https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-hill-52wuq?file=/src/App.tsx and it seems fine as well; can you provide an example of your config or somehting?

Comment: This issue seems to have resolved itself with a restart. Not sure why, because I'd already restarted since changing my tsconfig, adding packages etc. Still, thanks for your help and the useful tips on declaring/inferring.